# How to update Jenkins Job config.xml file using curl

Tags: jenkins

How can I edit jenkins job's parameter by updating config.xml of jenkins job using curl?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: curl -X POST -u username:password "jenkins_url/job/job_name/config.xml" --data-binary xml="<name>INPUT_PARAMETER_NAME</name><defaultValue>Input_parameter_value</defaultValue>"

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
curl -X POST 'http://my-cool-jenkins.com:8080/createItem?name=mycooljob' -u username:password --data-binary @config.xml -H "Content-Type:text/xml"
```

---

**Update:**

That url for creating job, for updating use:

```
curl -X POST 'http://my-cool-jenkins.com:8080/job/mycooljob/config.xml' -u username:password --data-binary @config.xml -H "Content-Type:text/xml"
```

Comment: I think this creates config.xml file? Is it true? I want to update existing one.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, my fault. In this case use url http://my-cool-jenkins.com:8080/job/mycooljob/config.xml

Comment: where can I pass Input parameter with new updated value? because my goal is to change input parameter's value

Comment: You can export your job config, modify it and upload back.
Export job XML: 
`curl 'http://my-cool-jenkins.com:8080/job/mycooljob/config.xml' -u username:password`

Answer (score 1):

Just updating content of config.xml file is probably not enough to change in-memory state of Jenkins job. You still need to reload configuration from disk, which can be done either in GUI with jenkins/manage/, [using groovy script](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/reloadJobConfig.groovy) or simply rebooting the server. After that your example should work.

This really goes down to the fact that Jenkins config.xml are XStream serialized java objects, not actual configuration files. So changing job parameters by manually editing xml files is likely not the best solution. Instead, you could change the job configuration using Jenkins script console. For example to change default parameter value for String parameter, you can run below script in Jenkins console (*e.g.* http://localhost:8080/jenkins/script):

```java
import hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty

def jobName = "job_name"
def paramName = "param_to_be_changed"
def newParamValue = "param_new_value"

def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)
def params = job.getAction(ParametersDefinitionProperty)

def paramToModify = params.getParameterDefinitions().find { param -> param.getName() == paramName }    

paramToModify.setDefaultValue(newParamValue)

job.save()
```

If the job is inside the folder or organization, it is necessary to go one level further, *i.e.*:

```java
def folderName = "folder_name"
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(folderName).getItem(jobName)
```

After that job state will be stored in config.xml file. After that you can execute the script remotely using curl. Assuming you saved above script to script.groovy file:

```sh
# Get breadcrumb from Jenkins
curl -u <username>:<password> 'http://localhost:8080/jenkins/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'
# Send script to Jenkins console
curl -X POST -u <username>:<password> -H 'Jenkins-Crumb: <crumb>' -H 'Content: text/plain' --data-urlencode "script=$(< script.groovy)"  http://localhost:8080/jenkins/scriptText
```

More details on Parameter API in [javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/ParameterDefinition.html)

Comment: Thanks I got point now. The first code snippet will change config.xml but this change is still not in-memory of jenkins job which can be done by the second curl command script.So I tried to do exact same thing, I copy and pasted first snippet & changed appropriate job name,parameter name and new value, but I am getting it gives me an error that "getAction()" is taking null value. Means ParametersDefinitionProperty is null. from where can I get this value?

Comment: getAction() returning null means simply that you have no parameters configured for the job. You can add one in GUI and try testing again. In script console, you can do that by creating new [ParameterDefinition](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/ParameterDefinition.html) and then your own [ParameterDefinitionProperty](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/ParametersDefinitionProperty.html) from it, using standard constructor. After that use addAction() method on your job. Though this is really different question.

Comment: No but I have already declared one parameter in my job and whenever I run it, it runs with that parameter's value. For example my param is RELEASE_VERSION and default value is 02.03.01 when I am running the job. now at the end of the job I want to modify this value to 02.03.02 and update RELEASE_VERSION for next run with new value

Comment: Strange, as the above example works with minimal installation (only recommended plugins) of Jenkins 2.7.4 and 2.99, both with Freestyle Project and Maven Module Set. Also, import is not mandatory, so the only way you can get "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAction() on null object" is by having null job. Check your script for typos and try to replicate the issue on clean Jenkins installation with one of the above versions.

Comment: I have Jenkins 2.60.3 version. Should I update it and give a try?

Comment: You can try, though it's unlikely the problem. What does job.getClass() and job.getAllActions() return for you, if you add it to above snippet?

Comment: import hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty

def jobName = "Input_Parameter"
def paramName = "RELEASE_VERSION"
def newParamValue = "20.00.00"

def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)
job.getClass()
job.getAllActions()
def params = job.getAction(ParametersDefinitionProperty)

def paramToModify = params.getParameterDefinitions().find { param -> param.getName() == paramName }    

paramToModify.setDefaultValue(newParamValue)

job.save()

Comment: ERROR: Build step failed with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAllActions() on null object
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)

Comment: So job with name "Input_Parameter" does not exist on your Jenkins instance? Check for typos in name or search  jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItems() whether the job exists at all.

Comment: The above script is not working for a jenkins job that is created inside a Folder. It works fine if job is created not inside any of folder but we should always consider a case for a job inside a Jenkins Folder.

Comment: I am getting an error for this line:def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(folderName).getItem(jobName) 
                                                 
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkins for class: Script1

Comment: import jenkins.model.Jenkins or jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItems()?

Comment: Mostly from http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/. There is good introduction to script console on [Jenkins official wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console) though.

Comment: sorry but now when same thing I am trying to put down in my Jenkins Pipeline script it is giving me an error at this line def params = job.getAction(ParametersDefinitionProperty) , so I guess import statement import hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty is not importing properly. is there any alternate way for this?

Comment: You should not try to run administrative scripts on Jenkins from pipeline. This is security risk explained in above link. Also it is not related to original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link of a script that I've been using in order to modify a job's pipeline for the shell: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iocanel/presentations/382074b5012d6c3ed87042298114e688424eeaed/workspace/editor/jenkins-run-pipeline